# How do I setup the FinishLocation on a flow?

Tags: workflow, flow, visual-workflow

We have certain accounts we use for only a very limited but very critical amount of information. I have created a Flow in Flow Designer (my apex knowledge is tiny) that gives my users access to only the fields they need to update.

How can I make it so that the 'Finish' button does not loop them back to the beginning?

I found [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_finishlocation.htm) but I can't figure out how to use it in Visual Flow or how to get to my flow and edit the code.

Comment: Are you using a Button to start the flow?

Comment: 1st you need to create a VF page. you need to create a VF page.

Comment: I set it up with a button at one point. Not sure if we're going to use it, but if that makes this work, then I probably will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring finish location in Visualflow depends on how you are using it. Following are the two scenarios by which you can set finish location for Visualflow and stop it from looping.

1. Calling Visualflow through Button.
   -> We need to use retURL when we are calling flow through a button URL.
   -> Implementation : example button url ::

> /flow/xyzflow?id=xxx00323xx&retURL=https://na12.salesforce.com/001

Documentation :: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_url_set_retURL.htm&language=en_US

NOTE : retURL defines where we need to redirect page once flow is finished.

2. Calling Visualflow through Visualforce Page.
   -> We need to embed VisualFlow in a VF Page and then we need to define finishLocation tag as it defines where page as to be redirected.
   -> Implementation  :

> ```
> <apex:page>
>     <flow:interview name="xyzflow" finishLocation="{!URLFOR('/xxx00323xx')}"/>
> </apex:page>
> ```

Please let me know if above information helps you :)

Cheers 
Tushar

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a VF page, listed by your resources you found.  Here is a [blog post](http://jimmitchell.org/salesforce-flows-visualforce-and-record-context/) which I found helpful.
2. Override your new/edit buttons on the account calling this VF page, or just create a new button for your users.

I like you don't touch APEX and makes my head hurt.  It took some work to getting it working.

However - Why don't you just use a different page layout for these users if they only need to update specific fields?

Comment: I can't create a different page layout as they need to access everything at other times. Not everyone is fully on board with our migration and I'm trying to eliminate headaches by giving them easy buttons.

Comment: That makes sense, just wanted to ask to be sure a sledge hammer was needed. ;)  If you don't want to use a button, maybe you can use an embedded VF page, which has the embedded flow?  That way when a users views the account record they see this section which is your flow, that guides them through a quick update?  Just a thought.  Here is an example of one I built: http://screencast.com/t/bWKQzsbN. (no audio)